# Why after connect to Google OAuth2 the result.Credential is null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I use the code below to authorize and refresh tokens to update some data in the Google sheet in my ASP.net MVC project,
I knew that after 1 hour, the token would expire, So I checked the expiration time and refreshed the token,
my problem in the below code is after 1 hour the result.Credential is null and result.redirectUri has value for connect account again!
I want to connect for a lifetime,
note:
FileDataStore works and save data to C:\Token

```
private async Task SendToGooggleSheet(List<string> columns, List<List<string>> rows, int formId, int answerId, string userId, string sheetid)
     {
        try
        {
            TempData["FormUserId"] = userId + "_" + formId;
            CancellationToken cancellationToken;
            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50));
            cancellationToken = cts.Token;
    
            var result = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetadata()).
               AuthorizeAsync(cancellationToken);
    
            if (result.Credential != null)
            {                   
    
                if (result.Credential.Token.IsExpired(SystemClock.Default))
                {
                    //var accessToekn = await result.Credential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync(); // this 2 line works for refresh token
                    var refreshResult = await result.Credential.RefreshTokenAsync(cancellationToken);
                }
    ....
            }
    ...
    }
    /////////////////////
    
        public class AppFlowMetadata : FlowMetadata
        {
            private static readonly IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                {
                    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId = ePoll.Model.GlobalApplicationData.GoogleDriveAuthorizationClientId,
                        ClientSecret = ePoll.Model.GlobalApplicationData.GoogleDriveAuthorizationSecretId
                    },
                    Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.DriveFile,SheetsService.Scope.DriveFile},
                    DataStore = new FileDataStore(ePoll.Model.GlobalApplicationData.GoogleSheetOauthSaveFolder, true), //C:\Token               
                });
    
            public override string GetUserId(Controller controller)
            {            
                var user = controller.TempData["FormUserId"];
                return user?.ToString();
            }
    
            public override IAuthorizationCodeFlow Flow
            {
                get { return flow; }
            }
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's related to the refresh token,
To force Google to return a new refresh token, you can add the prompt=consent parameter to your OAuth request.